# How to bind rowdata of ag-grid inside gridoption using a httpservice

Tags: angular6, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid license edition and want to bring record set to the grid using a service. I am using Ag-Grid gridoption property and initializing rowdata 
 in the constructor of  the component.ts class. But the data is not rendering. No error either. Please have a look of my component.ts class.

**Please note: the web api is returning the json data correctly and the service in Angular is tested sucessfully without Ag-Grid**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {GridOptions} from "ag-grid";
import {RedComponentComponent} from "../red-component/red-component.component";
import { person } from "../Shared/models/person.model";
import {personservice} from '../service/person.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-grid-application',
    templateUrl: './my-grid-application.component.html'
})
export class MyGridApplicationComponent implements OnInit{
    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
    private persons: person[];
    constructor(private personservice: personservice) {
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
        this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
            {
                headerName: "ID",
                field: "PersonId",
                width: 100
            },
            {
                headerName: "Name",
                field: "PersonNm",
                cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,
                width: 100
            },
            {
              headerName: "Email",
              field: "PersonEmail",
              cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,
              width: 100
          }

        ];

        this.gridOptions.rowData = this.persons

    }
    ngOnInit() {
      this.personservice.findAll().subscribe(
          persons => {
            this.persons = persons
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code written in .html page

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing `columnDefs` and `rowData` with `gridOptions`, try providing them directly like this.

```
<ag-grid-angular
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Also, declare `columnDefs` and `rowData` as component variables, and then assign *them* after getting the response.

```
rows: any[] = [];
columnDefs: ColDef[];

constructor(private personservice: personservice) {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
    this.columnDefs = [
        // your column definition goes here
    ];
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.personservice.findAll().subscribe(
      persons => {
        this.rows = persons
      },
      error => console.log(error)
  )
}
```

Let me know if you face any issue after this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, perhaps I have managed to get the solution through following implementation which is: